# Disk Decipher: iOS app with TrueCrypt and VeraCrypt functionality -- Has there been any security review? Is it safe to use?

Tags: ios, truecrypt

http://disk-decipher.hekkihek.nl/

I am having trouble finding information about source code, software license, and code review. Is there any way to know that once I decrypt a volume with this app it's not just sending my private data out to the internet?